# Apache Wicket Manually select a radio button along with its onEvent()

Tags: java, apache, wicket, wicket-1.5

Hi I'm new to Apache Wicket. I have a form and a Radio Group in it. After some form operation I want to keep a radioGroup to default selected value. I got it working somehow using

```
form.get( "radioChoices" ).setDefaultModelObject( "choice1" );
```

But 'choice1' has onEvent() method overridden to clear text fields and `setDefaultModelObject` doesn't calls choice1's onEvent() method. Is there any way to properly set radioGroup to 'choice1' that eventually calls its onEvent() method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PropertyModel that is linked to a String.

```
public class SomePage extends WebPage
{
   private String radioGroupChoice;   
   public SomePage()
   {
        radioGroupChoice = "choice1";
        RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup("group", new PropertyModel(this, "radioGroupChoice"));
   }
}
```

radioGroupChoice needs a get and a set method i order to work.

[Wicket wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Using+RadioGroups)